# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@android:drawable/logo.png

Tags: c#, android, xml

Firstly I am a beginner, learning to code by myself.
I am using Visual Studio Xamarin to create an android app. I am trying to put assign an image called logo.png to an imageview. I do not have a drawable file under the Resources file so I added a folder, named it 'drawable'. I then pasted the logo.png.
The xml code for the imageview:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/logo.png"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

I have not modified any java/ C# files.
Some of the unusual folders that I have under resources include mipmap-anydpi, mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, mipmap-xxxhdpi. I tried having the logo.png on all these folders and tried to build with the same xml code but no improvements. (btw I nearly do not know any xml). and in this case it says activity_main.axml compared to how it is on the Android Studio which has the name activity_main.axml. Does this have anything to do with the problem? I am following this tutorial by the way: https://youtu.be/WBTZ7TSan_E

Comment: Replace `@android:drawable/logo.png` with `@mipmap/logo`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android OS has its own resources, like color variables, default dimensions, themes etc.

If you use some internal drawable resources that exist in your phone, then you use:

```
android:src="@android:drawable/..."
```

If you use the resources that you add in your app, in your folder `drawable`, then use:

```
android:src="@drawable/..."
```

It's important to remember that, as you will run into that quite often.

Comment: IDK if its internal or resources that I add in the app. but it worked the latter one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you puted the `logo.png`:

on **src/drawable/** use `@drawable/logo.png`

if on **src/mipmap/** use `@mipmap/logo.png`

Why not `@android:`?

This path point to android resources, are default files, belongs to Android SDK

Comment: Thank you very much. both the code worked fine fortunately. Does it affect the speed or something. What could possibly be the reason why it didn't work when it was @android:drawable/logo and it worked when it was @drawable/logo.